# Write Excel Markos/Add-Ins in Python

Tags: python, excel, vba

I have been writing some Python Scripts and I would like to call them from my Excel application as an Add-In or Makro. Right now I am simply using VBA to start up Python and execute the script with the following code:

```
Sub AutoMail()

Dim objShell As Object
Dim PythonExe, PythonScript As String
    
    Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    PythonExe = """J:\Strasser\My_PythonInterpreter\Scripts\python.exe"""
    PythonScript = "J:\Strasser\Strasser_Py_Tests\main.py"
    
    objShell.Run PythonExe & PythonScript
      
End Sub
```

Some remarks regarding this specific script: It opens a "tkinter" Input window, does some calculations and opens the results in a new Excel sheet. (These results will then be used in the current Excel workbook..)

My question is, what is the "right" way to do this?

It should be quit fast and somewhat easy to use for my collegues and if possible for free (I have seen that I would have to buy for PyXLL for example.)

Thanks in advance for any responses!

Comment: Use Wlwings in their free version, I'd say it works for 90% of the things. You can bring the results either to [VBA or to a sheet](https://pythoninoffice.com/automate-excel-with-python-xlwings/) (though having the option to bring it back to VBA speeds up so much the process). As an off topic but related to demonstrate how useful xlwings is, I do have an example using [tensorflow in excel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVpaAiYeLGU)

Comment: The correct way is to pick one tool and do everything from it. My advice is to use VBA for Excel because it was designed to work that way. If you want to use Python, do everything from Python. There are tools like [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) that can manipulate Excel workbooks without even having Excel installed on the computer. This has it's obvious use cases. It's not as powerful as Excel but it is faster.

Comment: @HackSlash 
I know it is better to do everything in Python or VBA but the thing is that I know basically no VBA but I need the programms that I write to be available in Excel.

Would something like generating a .exe file be faster in some way?

Comment: @Sgdva XLwings looks exactly like the thing I need but it is only free for 30 days.. :(

Comment: @PaulStrasser it's not, follow the tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QSl1vYcDuF4), as I said, the free version will you get covered

Comment: @Sgdva
Oh true. You are totally right.. I just didnt find it on the website. 
here is the link to their website: https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/

I am not sure if other collegues can use this without having to install python and so on.. I will look into that. 
thanks for the help!

Comment: They need python and all the libraries that you use as well so they don't run into problems